# Launch jQuery Calculator By Clicking input-group-addon

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to launch a jQuery calculator (http://keith-wood.name/calculator.html) when clicking the calculator icon to the right of the input field.  The referenced calculator is great and has great documentation, but I guess I need someone smarter than me to figure out how to launch it when clicking the "fa-calculator" icon to the right of a field.

I've setup my form input field as follows.  The calculator allows the use of a button to launch it, but it simply creates a button next to the field, which isn't what I'm after.

Thank you!

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">A</span>
    <input name="a" id="a" class="c form-control input-mini" type="text">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calculator"></i></span>
</div>
```

I'm launching the calculator as below, and it works fine when an operator (+-*/) is typed.  But, I also need the calculator to launch when the input-group-addon is clicked.

```
$('#a').calculator({showOn:'operator'});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show the calculator by yourself when the user clicks on `.input-group-addon`, like this:

```js
$('.input-group-addon').on('click', function() {
  $('#basicCalculator').calculator('show');
});
```

http://keith-wood.name/calculatorRef.html#show

```js
$('#basicCalculator').calculator({
  showOn: 'operator',
});

$('.input-group-addon').on('click', function() {
  $('#basicCalculator').calculator('show');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.calculator@2.0.1/jquery.calculator.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.calculator@2.0.1/jquery.plugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.calculator@2.0.1/jquery.calculator.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="basicCalculator">
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calculator"></i></span>
```

https://jsbin.com/tukuyep/edit?html,js,output